# Splitting rows based on XML values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT distinct
    Thing.EncryptedId as 'Displayed ID'
    , Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName as 'User Name'
    , Thing.DateSubmitted as 'Submission Date'    
    , Specifics.DetailsXML    
FROM Thing
FULL JOIN Stuff ON Thing.OrderID = Stuff.OrderID
FULL JOIN Specifics ON Stuff.StuffID = Specifics.StuffID
FULL JOIN Users ON Thing.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE Thing.IsPresent = 1
```

"Specifics.DetailsXML" includes XML in following format:

```
<GeneralData
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <UserNumber>8X3A40</UserNumber>
  <PermanentAdjust>false</PermanentAdjust>
  <Description />
  <ConfirmationOption>
    <_description>No Confirmation</_description>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Description>No Confirmation</Description>
  </ConfirmationOption>
  <ResponseType>
    <Code>01</Code>
  </ResponseType>
  <TotalImpact>0</TotalImpact>
  <LabelFolder>\\labels\place\general</LabelFolder>

  <SeparateInstances>
    <InstanceItem>
      <Track>10</Track>
      <Dimension>25</Dimension>
      <InstanceLeadNumber>22754015</InstanceLeadNumber>
      <InstancePath>22754015\22754015</InstancePath>
    </InstanceItem>
    <InstanceItem>
      <Track>10</Track>
      <Dimension>25</Dimension>
      <InstanceLeadNumber>22754016</InstanceLeadNumber>
      <InstancePath>22754015\22754016</InstancePath>
    </InstanceItem>
  </SeparateInstances>
</GeneralData>
```

I need to extract all "InstancePath"es as separate values and each XML can have more than 2 "InstanceItem"s with those.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: FYI `Thing.EncryptedId as 'Displayed ID'` should be `Thing.EncryptedId as [Displayed ID]` in SQL Server. Using single quotes can result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Is it possible for DetailsXML to contain no InstanceItem nodes? Do you want the query to return the other columns when that is the case?

Comment: > @AlwaysLearning
Yes, that's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conceptual example for you how to shred XML into a relational/rectangular format.

You can put it into a CTE, and after that join with the rest of the tables.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, DetailsXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (DetailsXML) VALUES
(N'<GeneralData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <UserNumber>8X3A40</UserNumber>
    <PermanentAdjust>false</PermanentAdjust>
    <Description/>
    <ConfirmationOption>
        <_description>No Confirmation</_description>
        <Id>0</Id>
        <Description>No Confirmation</Description>
    </ConfirmationOption>
    <ResponseType>
        <Code>01</Code>
    </ResponseType>
    <TotalImpact>0</TotalImpact>
    <LabelFolder>\\labels\place\general</LabelFolder>
    <SeparateInstances>
        <InstanceItem>
            <Track>10</Track>
            <Dimension>25</Dimension>
            <InstanceLeadNumber>22754015</InstanceLeadNumber>
            <InstancePath>22754015\22754015</InstancePath>
        </InstanceItem>
        <InstanceItem>
            <Track>10</Track>
            <Dimension>25</Dimension>
            <InstanceLeadNumber>22754016</InstanceLeadNumber>
            <InstancePath>22754015\22754016</InstancePath>
        </InstanceItem>
    </SeparateInstances>
</GeneralData>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT id
    , c.value('(InstancePath/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS InstancePath
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY DetailsXML.nodes('/GeneralData/SeparateInstances/InstanceItem') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |   InstancePath    |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | 22754015\22754015 |
|  1 | 22754015\22754016 |
+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need `.nodes` to shred your XML, and `.value` to pull the actual text out.**

It's unclear why you have a `DISTINCT` here, or three `FULL JOIN`s, it's certainly an unusual query. But because of that, you need to place it in a derived subquery in order to get the `DISTINCT` working correctly (otherwise it will only return distinct `InstancePath`). Without that, you could just add the `.nodes` directly to your existing query.

```sql
SELECT *,
    x.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS InstancePath
FROM (
    SELECT distinct
        Thing.EncryptedId as [Displayed ID]
        , Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName as [User Name]
        , Thing.DateSubmitted as [Submission Date]
        , Specifics.DetailsXML    
    FROM Thing
    FULL JOIN Stuff ON Thing.OrderID = Stuff.OrderID
    FULL JOIN Specifics ON Stuff.StuffID = Specifics.StuffID
    FULL JOIN Users ON Thing.UserID = Users.UserID
    WHERE Thing.IsPresent = 1
) t
OUTER APPLY Specifics.DetailsXML.nodes('/GeneralData/SeparateInstances/InstanceItem/InstancePath') x
```